# Can't change my custom logo for Bartik-theme. How to fix this?

Tags: 7, files

Have newly installed Drupal 7 . Tried to change my logo to a custom logo. Worked the first time. Theme Bartik was activated. Now wanna change the logo a second time, can't do it. Can't disable it. Appearence->Settings->Custom Logo won't change or when i uncheck Logo nothing happens. Switched appearance to Stark,   everything worked as expected. Switched back to Bartik no logo-change-feature anymore / still the old logo.

Any suggestions/help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on your files directory on your server?

Comment: Instead of commenting, go ahead and answer your own question.  On this site, it's OK (and encouraged!) to answer your own question when you solve your own problem.

Comment: I have the same problem in Drupal 9.4.1. I did check that all folders have permissions a+x  and the logo file has a+r (all can read). When I try to access the image file directly, it says that there is a server misconfiguration. But it is an automatic installation by the host (nuxit.com) and all else works. (Had to disable CCS aggregation, though, to see the correct layout.)

Comment: There's a .htaccess file which has just standard settings : "Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews" and "  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003"
" and an "php_flag engine off" (which I don't know well) might that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me. There exists global settings / bartik settings etc. I was convinced i used global settings all the time but nope, and if you specify a bartik logo, it overrides the global one. Thank you for trying to help me.